# Clicking a button in UIActionSheet causes my app to crash

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, button, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to implement a UIActionSheet which will have some sharing buttons on it for sharing to twitter, facebook, email and print.

Here is my share view controller.h

```
@interface ShareViewController : UITableViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *services;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActionSheet *actionSheet;
@property (strong, nonatomic) id <ShareViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popCon;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *serviceTitle;

-(IBAction)loadActionSheet:(id)sender;
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex;
- (void)tweetThis;
- (void)printThis;
- (void)openMail;
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error;


@end
```

Here is my share view controller.m

```
-(IBAction)loadActionSheet:(id)sender{
if (self.actionSheet) {
            // do nothing
} 
else {
UIActionSheet *sharing = [[UIActionSheet alloc] 
                          initWithTitle:nil 
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:nil 
                          destructiveButtonTitle:nil 
                          otherButtonTitles:@"Twitter", @"Facebook", @"Email", @"Print", nil];

[sharing showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
}
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{

     NSLog(@"Button index: %d",buttonIndex);
switch (buttonIndex) {
    case 0:
        [self tweetThis];
        break;
    case 1:
        [self sendToFacebook];
        break;
    case 2:
        NSLog(@"email");
        [self openMail];
        break;
    case 3:
        NSLog(@"Print");
        [self printThis];
        break;
    default:
        NSLog(@"Error");
        break;
}
}
```

I ma initiaalising my share view controller in main view controller.m as follows:

```
- (IBAction)shareButtonTapped:(id)sender {

ShareViewController *svc = [[ShareViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UIActionSheetStyleDefault];
[svc loadActionSheet:(id)sender];

}
```

I can open the action sheet fine, but when I click on any of the buttons, it crashes the app. Any ideas as to why?

Comment: Can you provide the crash log?

Comment: you should also be doing `self.actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] init...];`

Comment: jacerate, I added that in, thanks. The main issue still persists, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most likely a memory-management issue. It looks like you're using ARC, so after the `shareButtonTapped` method returns, ARC will automatically release `svc`, as it's no longer referenced anywhere. The delegate property of the action sheet is `weak`, so it's not retained by that either.

I don't really see why `ShareViewController` is a view controller in the first place, as you never seem to be loading its view, but you may have your reasons... In any case, you should make that controller a `strong` property or instance variable of your other (main) view controller, so that it's not automatically released before the action sheet finishes.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try this now. You're right, the initial purpose of ShareViewController changed, so it is no longer required to be a view controller. I'll change it to and NSObject now and make an instance variable of the main view controller

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Go to your .xib file.

You should see all the buttons you have.

Click on a button and go to the "Connections Inspector"

Delete the referencing outlet.

Drag the referencing outlet to the button and set the button to the "ID" you want.

Let me know if that works.

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm creating the action sheet programmatically. Are you referring to the button I click to launch the action sheet, or the buttons within the action sheet? The button to launch he action sheet is in the .xib file, But that works ok at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Just a stupid answer - the methods like - (void) sendToFacebook; are implemented, right?

Comment: They are, yes. I just left them out to make it easier to read. I debugged it to see if they're getting called, and they aren't.