# App crashed when trying to invoke UIActionSheet from my custom class

Tags: objective-c, ios7, automatic-ref-counting, uiactionsheet

I'm trying to do a simple reusable class which will fire up an action sheet to chose pic from library or camera and then crop the image and just return the final image to caller.

But when I tap on any button in UIActionSheet, its getting crashed showing `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Here is the code:
In my `MainViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)ClickOnAdd:(id)sender{
    ImagePickerControl *pickerControl = [[ImagePickerControl alloc] initWithController:self Title:@"Chose Image" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" fromLibraryTitle:@"Library" fromCameraTitle:@"Camera"];
    [pickerControl showInView:self.view];  
}
```

Code in ImagePickerControl.h

```
@protocol ImagePickerControlDelegate;

@interface ImagePickerControl : NSObject<UIActionSheetDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate,UINavigationControllerDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) UIActionSheet *menuSheet;
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIViewController *parentViewController;

- (id)initWithController:(UIViewController*) viewController Title:(NSString *)title delegate:(id<ImagePickerControlDelegate>)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle fromLibraryTitle:(NSString *)fromLibTitle fromCameraTitle:(NSString *)fromCamTitle;

-(void)showInView:(UIView*) parentView;
@end

@protocol ImagePickerControlDelegate <NSObject>


// Called when an image is picked. The view will be automatically dismissed after this call returns
- (void)imagePickerControlDidPickImage:(ImagePickerControl *)imagePickerControl pickedImage:(UIImage*)selectedImage;

// Called when we cancel the control's view
- (void)imagePickerControlDidCancel:(ImagePickerControl *)imagePickerControl;
@end
```

And finally in `ImagePickerControl.m`

```
- (id)initWithController:(UIViewController*) viewController Title:(NSString *)title delegate:(id<NTImagePickerControlDelegate>)delegate cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle fromLibraryTitle:(NSString *)fromLibTitle fromCameraTitle:(NSString *)fromCamTitle
{
    if(self = [super init]){
        self.menuSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:title
                                                delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
                                                destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                                otherButtonTitles:fromLibTitle,fromCamTitle,nil];

        self.parentViewController = viewController;


    }
    return self;
}

-(void)showInView:(UIView*) parentView
{
    [self.menuSheet showInView:parentView];
}

//This method was not called at all
-(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
}
```

After a quick research, from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512056/clicking-a-button-in-uiactionsheet-causes-my-app-to-crash), I think, its clear that my control class gets released after i invoke. But in the answer there, it is mentioned to assign the controller as a strong property to mainviewcontroller. But I dont want to use this by creating a property and assigning. Just simply call it on add button click and get the callbacks, just like we use UIActionSheet or UIAlertView.

One more note is that, in my `ClickOnAdd` method, if I remove my custom class and add UIActionSheet itself there, then the callbacks are working fine. I'm expecting the same behaviour using my class. How that can be done?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned in the other answer, your `ImagePickerControl` is deallocated before the button is tapped. Therefore your app crashes.

You should assign the picker controller to a strong ivar in `ClickOnAdd` method. Then in your callback (I assume `MainViewController` gets a callback when the button is tapped) you should set this ivar to `nil` so that the picker controller is released.

It could work without an `ivar` if you weren't using `ARC`. In that case, you can keep the picker controller in the memory by not releasing it on `ClickOnAdd` and manually releasing it on the callback. However, that is just an invitation to memory leaks, therefore I would use a retained property even with `non-ARC` code.

`UIActionSheet` is a subclass of `UIView` therefore I assume it is added to the view hierarchy when you call `showInView` and therefore retained. It is probably released as soon as it is removed from the hierarchy so it is also good to keep a strong reference to it just in case it gets released sooner than you expected.

Comment: Ok..I got the point clear. addSubview will retain the UIActionSheet. So is there any way I can retain my imagePickerControl in its class itself? Since I'm using ARC, retain, release and all are not available.

Comment: The picker control should not retain itself. The lifetime of the picker control should be managed by your `MainViewController` class or any other class that is using it. Otherwise you will face a similar problem when the `MainViewController` is deallocated and the picker control calls its callback method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem of your code is that your action sheet is deallocated by the time of clickButton at index.

You can easily get it by enabling Zombie Objects in Diagnostics tab (see attach).

In your case you should get error like

```
-[ImagePickerControl actionSheet:clickedButtonAtIndex:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

So your *pickerControl* should be iVar in the initiating controller.

[image]

Comment: I dont want it to be an iVar or property. If I give UIActionSheet directly, there is no crash. Hows that working then?

Comment: The difference is that in case of ordinary UIActionSheet you assign your viewController as delegate in 
-(id)initWithTitle:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:

and it really gets click button event while your action sheet is deallocated at this time. But it is not the problem in such situation.

In your case UIActionSheet delegate is ImagePickerControl itself. ImagePickerControl lives only in scope of ClickOnAdd: method.